# How to calculate the number of specific text in each line?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know how can I calculate the number of yes expressions in each row (the columns which contains yes/no are from I to R) and 10 lines.

I used this formula but it didn't work

`=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",(ARRAYFORMULA(if(I2:I="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(J2:J="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(K2:K="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(L2:L="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(M2:M="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(N2:N="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(O2:O="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(P2:P="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Q2:Q="Oui",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(R2:R="Oui",1,0))),""))`

("Oui" means "yes".)

Comment: it didn't work .

Comment: I tried another formula

Comment: =arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"",(ARRAYFORMULA(if(I2:I="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(J2:J="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(K2:K="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(L2:L="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(M2:M="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(N2:N="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(O2:O="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(P2:P="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Q2:Q="OUI",1,0)))+(ARRAYFORMULA(if(R2:R="OUI",1,0)))"")) but it didn't work error parse formula

Comment: It would be useful if you added some sample data. Also, don't put important information in the comments; they're meant to be temporary. If you've tried a new formula, [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Also, in what way "doesn't it work"? Does it throw an error? Give an incorrect result? Please [edit] this into your question so we have a chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're trying to do this as an array?

It sounds like you are looking to count each row individually (not all rows together), is that right? If so, I am not sure if it is possible with an array formula because they seem to count the entire range even if I try to tell it to count each row separately. Someone else might know more than I, though.

If a regular formula would work for you, you could use the following in every row of an empty column:

```
=countif(j2:r2,"*oui*")
```

If you want the formula result to be blank every time the data is blank (as you were attempting in your attempted array formula) you could use:

```
=if(b2="","",countif(j2:r2,"*oui*")
```

I hope that helps.

Note: I use the * wildcard because some people design their RSVP forms with an option such as "Yes, I will attend" and this will find anything that contains "Yes."

Comment: Note i want to count this yes experession in each row and not in each column